# UITableView with NSArray gives "index beyond bounds" error

Tags: uitableview, nsarray

I have some experience with using tableviews. This time, I tried loading it from an array (well, technically, from a dictionary, but the allKeys parameter is an NSArray), however, I just get this exception

```
-[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 10 beyond bounds [0 .. 9]
```

Now, my array is 11 keys long, which means it would be counted as 10 (since Obj-C counts 0 as well). Here it says it's count is 9. I have tried several different methods:

- Moving the initialisation of the dictionary to `- (void)awakeFromNib`
- Creating a separate `NSArray` with all the keys
- Just listing `11`

But they all give me the exception!

### Update

I noticed some of you were saying that my array is only 10 objects long, but if I set it to `10`, I get one object missing:

[image: As you can see, there are 11 keys]

The breakpoint tells 11...

[image]

There's no "Acceleration X" item when using 10 items, see?

[image]

And `NSLog`says differently than 10, in the same method as returning the amount of rows

Comment: `NSArray` knows how to count, why don't you post the array population code

Comment: > Now, my array is 11 keys long

Your problem seems to be that it is only 10 keys long.

Comment: I can assure you that there are only 10 elements in that array.  NSLog the array before the offending statement, to see it's contents.

Comment: Make sure that one of your keys isn't a duplicate.

Comment: Maybe your 11th element is null instead of @"0", in that case the array would be seen as having 10 elements, since arrays are null terminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact of the matter is that your array is 10 items long. The comments above aren't saying "you should remove "Acceleration X" to make it 10 items long", they're saying "you're mistaken in your belief that your array is 11 items long".

Without seeing more code, it's difficult to say what's really going on here; but anyway, you shouldn't be using `-allValues`, because the ordering in that array is undefined, which makes it unsuitable for use backing a table view.

Instead, you should keep an array of the keys of the dictionary in whatever order you want them to display, and then reference `_items[key]` directly.

For example:

```
_keys = 
@[
    @"Red",
    @"Orange",
    @"Yellow",
    @"Green",
    @"Blue",
    @"Indigo",
    @"Violet"
];

_dictionary = 
@{
    @"Blue": @"Battle",
    @"Green": @"Gave",
    @"Indigo": @"In",
    @"Orange": @"Of",
    @"Red": @"Richard",
    @"Violet": @"Vain"
    @"Yellow": @"York",
};

- (NSString *)labelTextForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return _keys[indexPath.row];
}

- (NSString *)detailLabelTextForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return _dictionary[_keys[indexPath.row]];
}
```

Comment: Well, creating a C array + dict. worked well, thanks!